Create session on start of application in Laravel
I have two user logins and an admin login in my application. For user login, I want to generate one session at the start of the application for using this code:
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CartController;

  public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CartController::class, function ($app) {
            return CartController::createTempSession();
        });
    }

In cart controller:
public function createTempSession(Request $request)
    { 
        $guestSessId= session()->get('guestSessId', function() {
            return session()->put('guestSessId', uniqid('guest_', true));
         });
    }

I got no error, but the session is not created when I get the session, no data is retrieved, and I want to set the session for only the user, not the admin (guards). Any solutions?

You are binding something to the container, when is that binding being resolved? .... also what version of Laravel are you using, you can't be using 5.X, 6, 7 and 8

bindings are registered in the register method btw .. also your binding isn't returning anything, so what are you trying to do?

@lagbox I'm using laravel 8 and i want to create session with a random guid when user hits any route on application

@user3653474 You probably want a middleware.

Ensure that your session configuration in config/session.php is properly set to use a persistent session driver such as file or database.
And the use of session() inside a service provider could be unexpectedly due to Laravel’s session driver not having booted completely at this stage of the application lifecycle.
But you could rather handle session management within middleware or directly within the controller methods that require it instead of binding CartController with a session initialization. So try this:
Use Artisan to create a new middleware:
php artisan make:middleware InitializeUserSession

Edit the middleware to include session initialization:
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InitializeUserSession
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Always ensure a session ID is set, whether the user is logged in or a guest
        if (!$request->session()->has('guestSessId')) {
            $request->session()->put('guestSessId', uniqid('guest_', true));
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}

Register your middleware in the kernel.php:
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'init.session' => \App\Http\Middleware\InitializeUserSession::class,
];

Apply this middleware globally or to specific routes that involve cart operations. For a global setting, you can add it to the web middleware group in the same Kernel.php file:
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\InitializeUserSession::class,
        // other web middlewares...
    ],
];

So, to use the darryldecode/cart package effectively with the session ID you've established, try configure it to use the session ID from your middleware:
use Cart;

public function addToCart(Request $request)
{
    $productId = $request->input('product_id');
    $quantity = $request->input('quantity', 1);

    $cart = Cart::session($request->session()->get('guestSessId'));
    $cart->add($productId, 'Product Name', 10.00, $quantity);

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Product added to cart successfully!']);
}

public function showCart(Request $request)
{
    $cart = Cart::session($request->session()->get('guestSessId'));
    $cartContent = $cart->getContent();

    return view('cart.index', compact('cartContent'));
}

and try to clear your application cache (php artisan cache:clear) and your configuration cache (php artisan config:clear) after you made this changes to ensure that all changes are correctly applied.

Thanks i tried the above code but when i access it i get null, if a user is not logged in then also need to generate one session id can you pls let me know the issue, using this https://packagist.org/packages/darryldecode/cart package i want to save products to cart after generating random session for guest users also

If you awant to generate a session ID for every visitor , logged-in users and guests,and use it to manage cart operations with the darryldecode/cart package, you will need to adjust your approach slightly. The session needs to be created for both guests and logged-in users, so that the cart can be managed uniformly.

I made a change in my post, take a look
